# How to do sidewaystable

Tags: color, rotating

I have a very broad table in one of my appendices LaTeX so I wanted to have it sideways. However, when I use `sidewaystable`, the table is placed on another page directly after my appendix, leaving my document with a nearly blank page with only the name of my appendix on it. I know that the flipped table can be fitted on there, but LaTeX decides to not to for some reason.

I then used `hvfloat`, but then I can't change the style of the captions to fit the style of my other, normal tables.

I also used `rotating`, which was the best option for it. However, the table contains numbers in the next format `(2.6 $\pm$ 5.6)$\cdot 10^{-4}$` which I can't align properly. I used `siunitx` for that, but couldn't figure it out how to get it right in the center. So at this moment, I'm stranded with a lot of manual adjustments which are just a lot of work and look ugly:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hvfloat,rotating}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
\usepackage{a4wide, afterpage, amsmath, amssymb, babelbib, booktabs, cite, color, colortbl, dcolumn, emptypage, eurosym, graphicx, float, footmisc, hyperref, hvfloat ,natbib, listings, lmodern, longtable, pdflscape, rotating, siunitx, subcaption, tablefootnote, threeparttable, titlesec, url}

\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
   \rowcolors{7}{}{lightgray}
   \centering
   \rotatebox{90}{
   \begin{minipage}{0.7\paperheight}
      \caption{Overzicht van de concentraties en hun standaardeviaties van pesticiden in mg/kg in de (on)behandelde wortelen en de meelwormen gekweekt op deze wortelen. Bij NA lag de concentratie onder de detectielimiet van de LCMS-MS.} \label{conc_carrot_meal}
      \scalebox{0.8}{
         \begin{tabular}{c*{6}{r@{.}l@{ $\pm$ }r@{.}l}}
         \hline
         \textbf{Pesticiden} & \multicolumn{24}{c}{\textbf{Concentraties pesticiden (mg/kg)}} \\ \cmidrule{2-25} 
         & \multicolumn{12}{c}{\textbf{Onbehandeld}}  & \multicolumn{12}{c}{\textbf{Behandeld}} \\ \cmidrule{2-13} \cmidrule(lr){14-25}
          & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Wortel}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\begin{tabular}{c}
\textbf{ Meelwormen } \\
 \textbf{(voor gut-loading)} \\
 \end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\begin{tabular}{c}
\textbf{ Meelwormen} \\
 \textbf{(na gut-loading)} \\
 \end{tabular}}  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Wortel}}  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\begin{tabular}{c}
\textbf{ Meelwormen} \\
 \textbf{(voor gut-loading)} \\
 \end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\begin{tabular}{c}
\textbf{ Meelwormen} \\
 \textbf{(na gut-loading)} \\
 \end{tabular}} \\
\hline \hline
         2,4-D & \hspace{2ex}(2&55 & 2&6)$\cdot 10^{-4}$ & \hspace{2ex}(9&73 & 6&39)$\cdot 10^{-4}$ & \hspace{2ex}(8&24 & 2&77)$\cdot 10^{-4}$ & \hspace{2ex}(8&36 & 0&841) & \hspace{2ex}(5&01 & 0&542)$\cdot 10^{-4}$ & \hspace{2ex}(6&77 & 1&86)$\cdot 10^{-4}$\\
         Bentazon & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\hspace{2.5ex}NA} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\hspace{2.5ex}NA} & \hspace{2ex}(1&59 & 2&76)$\cdot 10^{-5}$ & \hspace{2ex}(0&919 & 0&117) & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\hspace{2.5ex}NA} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\hspace{2.5ex}NA} \\
         Bifenthrin & \hspace{2ex}(1&66 & 0&146)$\cdot 10^{-3}$ & \hspace{2ex}(2&84 & 1&15)$\cdot 10^{-3}$ & \hspace{2ex}(3&04 & 1&30)$\cdot 10^{-3}$ & \hspace{2ex}(0&808 & 0&104) & (2&22 & 0&769)$\cdot 10^{-3}$ & \hspace{2ex}(1&93 & 0&151)$\cdot 10^{-3}$ \\
         Clopyralid  & \hspace{2ex}(9&18 & 0&149)$\cdot 10^{-5}$ & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\hspace{2.5ex}NA} & \hspace{2ex}(4&61 & 7&99)$\cdot 10^{-5}$ & \hspace{2ex}(1&75 & 0&155) & \hspace{2ex}(1&07 & 0&686)$\cdot 10^{-2}$ & \hspace{2ex}(6&84 & 2&40)$\cdot 10^{-3}$ \\
         \hline
         \end{tabular}}
      \end{minipage}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This works but I need the rows to be coloured gray, but because of this, some numbers are disappearing:

[image: Disappearing numbers in my gray rows].

I really don't know what other solutions I can possibly use and it's driving me crazy after several hours searching for it.

Comment: You could use the `landscape` environment of the `lscape` package to rotate a single page containing your table. However, the text surrounding the table will not be placed on that page.

Answer (score 3):

The intermittent disappearing numbers problem is caused by the complicated tabular structure. I suggest you simplify the table code drastically, reducing the number of columns from 25 to 7 in the process. The positions of some of the cells can be fine-tuned with judiciously provided `\phantom{0}` statements. This fine-tuning would be entirely unnecessary, by the way, if you simply listed all numbers with exactly two digits after the decimal marker.

I would also like to suggest you (re)organize the table header some more. Personally, I'm not a fan of rendering every single header cell in **bold**. The result of too much (visual) shouting is that the message becomes very hard to hear.

With these adjustments, the table *barely* fits inside the available text block even when set in landscape mode. It won't fit on a page with a chapter or sectioning header unless you do something (potentially ugly) such as reducing the font size used in the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
%%% I've commented out packages that are either loaded automatically by
%%% other packages or conflict with other packages.
%%% Note that "hyperref" should generally be loaded _last_
%\usepackage{hvfloat,rotating}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{a4wide, afterpage, %amsmath, 
   amssymb, babelbib, booktabs, cite, %color, colortbl, 
   dcolumn, emptypage, eurosym, %graphicx, 
   float, footmisc,  hvfloat ,%natbib, 
   listings, lmodern, longtable, pdflscape, rotating,   
   siunitx, subcaption, tablefootnote, threeparttable, 
   titlesec, url, hyperref}

\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}

\newcommand\PA{\phantom{0}}  % shortcut macro

\begin{document}


\begin{sidewaystable}
\rowcolors{7}{}{lightgray}
\caption[Overzicht van de concentraties en hun standaardeviaties van pesticiden]{Overzicht van de concentraties en hun standaardeviaties van pesticiden in mg/kg in de (on)behandelde wortelen en de meelwormen gekweekt op deze wortelen. Bij NA lag de concentratie onder de detectielimiet van de LCMS-MS.} 
\label{conc_carrot_meal}

\centering
\begin{tabular}{ l *{6}{c} }
\toprule
{Pesticiden} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{{Concentraties pesticiden (mg/kg)}} \\ 
\cmidrule(l){2-7}  & 
\multicolumn{3}{c}{{Onbehandeld}}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{{Behandeld}} \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
&{Wortel} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{{Meelwormen}} &{Wortel} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{{Meelwormen}}\\
\cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(l){6-7}
& & voor gut-loading & na gut-loading & & voor gut-loading & na gut-loading\\
\midrule
2,4-D      & $(2.55 \pm 2.6\PA\PA){\cdot} 10^{-4}$ 
           & $(9.73 \pm 6.39){\cdot} 10^{-4} $ 
           & $(8.24 \pm 2.77  ){\cdot} 10^{-4}$ 
           & $(8.36\PA\pm 0.841) $
           & $(5.01 \pm 0.542 ){\cdot} 10^{-4}$ 
           & $(6.77 \pm 1.86\PA){\cdot} 10^{-4}$\\
Bentazon   & NA 
           & NA 
           & $(1.59  \pm 2.76){\cdot} 10^{-5}$ 
           & $(0.919 \pm 0.117)$
           & NA 
           & NA \\
Bifenthrin & $(1.66  \pm 0.146){\cdot} 10^{-3}$ 
           & $(2.84  \pm 1.15){\cdot} 10^{-3}$ 
           & $(3.04  \pm 1.30){\cdot} 10^{-3}$ 
           & $(0.808 \pm 0.104) $
           & $(2.22  \pm 0.769){\cdot} 10^{-3}$ 
           & $(1.93  \pm 0.151){\cdot} 10^{-3}$ \\
Clopyralid & $(9.18  \pm 0.149){\cdot} 10^{-5}$ 
           & NA 
           & $(4.61  \pm 7.99){\cdot} 10^{-5}$ 
           & $(1.75\PA\pm 0.155)$
           & $(1.07  \pm 0.686){\cdot} 10^{-2}$ 
           & $(6.84  \pm 2.40\PA){\cdot} 10^{-3}$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: It's possible to set the entire table in portrait, i.e., non-rotated form by changing the font size to `\footnotesize`, showing only two digits after the decimal markers, and using a `tabular*` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
%%% I've commented out packages that are either loaded 
%%% automatically by or conflict with other packages.
%%% Note that "hyperref" should generally be loaded _last_.

%\usepackage{hvfloat,rotating}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}

\usepackage{a4wide, afterpage, %amsmath, 
   amssymb, babelbib, booktabs, cite, %color, colortbl, 
   dcolumn, emptypage, eurosym, %graphicx, 
   float, footmisc,  hvfloat ,%natbib, 
   listings, lmodern, longtable, pdflscape, rotating,   
   siunitx, subcaption, tablefootnote, threeparttable, 
   titlesec, url, hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out intercolumn space
\footnotesize
\captionsetup{size=footnotesize}
\caption[Overzicht van de concentraties en hun standaardeviaties van pesticiden]{Overzicht van de concentraties en hun standaardeviaties van pesticiden in mg/kg in de (on)behandelde wortelen en de meelwormen gekweekt op deze wortelen. Bij NA lag de concentratie onder de detectielimiet van de LCMS-MS.} 
\label{conc_carrot_meal}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{ l@{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{6}{c} }
\toprule
{Pesticiden} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{{Concentraties pesticiden (\si[per-mode = symbol]{\milli\gram\per\kilo\gram})}} \\ 
\cmidrule(l){2-7}  & 
\multicolumn{3}{c}{{Onbehandeld}}  & 
\multicolumn{3}{c}{{Behandeld}} \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
&{Wortel} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{{Meelwormen}} 
&{Wortel} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{{Meelwormen}}\\
\cmidrule{3-4} \cmidrule{6-7}
& & voor gut-loading & na gut-loading 
& & voor gut-loading & na gut-loading\\
\midrule
2,4-D      & $(2.55 {\pm} 2.60){\cdot} 10^{-4}$ 
           & $(9.73 {\pm} 6.39){\cdot} 10^{-4} $ 
           & $(8.24 {\pm} 2.77  ){\cdot} 10^{-4}$ 
           & $8.36 {\pm} 0.84 $
           & $(5.01 {\pm} 0.54 ){\cdot} 10^{-4}$ 
           & $(6.77 {\pm} 1.86){\cdot} 10^{-4}$\\
Bentazon   & NA 
           & NA 
           & $(1.59  {\pm} 2.76){\cdot} 10^{-5}$ 
           & $0.92  {\pm} 0.12$
           & NA 
           & NA \\
Bifenthrin & $(1.66  {\pm} 0.15){\cdot} 10^{-3}$ 
           & $(2.84  {\pm} 1.15){\cdot} 10^{-3}$ 
           & $(3.04  {\pm} 1.30){\cdot} 10^{-3}$ 
           & $0.81  {\pm} 0.10 $
           & $(2.22  {\pm} 0.77){\cdot} 10^{-3}$ 
           & $(1.93  {\pm} 0.15){\cdot} 10^{-3}$ \\
Clopyralid & $(9.18  {\pm} 0.15){\cdot} 10^{-5}$ 
           & NA 
           & $(4.61  {\pm} 7.99){\cdot} 10^{-5}$ 
           & $1.75  {\pm} 0.16$
           & $(1.07  {\pm} 0.69){\cdot} 10^{-2}$ 
           & $(6.84  {\pm} 2.40){\cdot} 10^{-3}$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick-and-dirty hack: You could typeset the table as full-page document on its own and include it as a rotated figure. Maintaining a separate tex file for the table would be annoying, but how often would you edit a table?

```
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[angle=90]{figure}
  \caption{The caption goes here}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Does this procedure guarantee that the figure will fit on a page in the target document?

Comment: You can use the height or width option in includegraphics to scale the figure. For example: `width=\textwidth`